# Is 'name.firstName_lastName.projectName' a correct package name without domain registration?

Tags: java, naming-conventions, package

I don't register a domain for my name, any thing like `www.firstName_lastName.name`.

Is `name.firstName_lastName.projectName` a correct package name without domain registration?

Note that my project is a personal project and I don't have any domain.

Comment: Java package names have long ceased to have anything to do with DNS.  Sun dropped that daft idea pretty quickly. You can use any package name you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed package name is *technically* correct but please note some things:

- A package name has nothing to do with a domain name - it is nowaddays only a rough indication where the package belongs to (e.g. "org.apache.foo" just *indicates* that the Apache website *might* have updates, docs, ...)
- A '_' in the package name is *absolutely* uncommon. You should not start with this.
- Packagenames should be hierarchical - from top to bottom when reading from left to right. I'm not sure if the first `name` part in your example does fit or not.

Rationale: Just start with something simple like

```
org.myprojectname
```

After a while you will have seen enough other libraries, frameworks and then you get the feeling about what is accepted practice.